# Any way to extend/hack the ABAP 30 characters long limit?

Tags: abap

ABAP variables, classes, methods, etc [may be up to 30 characters long](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/EN/fc/eb3034358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm).

This is a very annoying limit, specially when you want to name things properly (for example, an unit test name).

Is there any way to extend or hack this limit?

Comment: Do you have sample names you would want to use that dont fit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't be able to work around this because you would have to change loads of kernel structures for this.